# Bash scripting - how to concatenate the following strings?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

Here is the part of the `bash` script doing `cpuid` discovery in Linux (Ubuntu/Fedora):

```
/usr/bin/cpuid > id.txt    
CPUID=id.txt    
echo `grep "extended model" $CPUID` | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } ' > cpu.txt    
a=`cat cpu.txt`    
echo `grep "extended family" $CPUID`| sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } ' > cpu.txt    
a+=`cat cpu.txt`
```

So, for my laptop this part of the script (shown here) gives 60.

Now how to do this using ONLY local variables, not having intermediate file (`cpu.txt`) involved?

Answer (score 10):

In one go:

```
printf '%s%s\n' "$(grep -Pom1 'extended model.*\(\K\d+' <(cpuid))" \
                "$(grep -Pom1 'extended family.*\(\K\d+' <(cpuid))"
```

The above leverages process substitution (`<()`), and command substitution (`$()`).

- The two command substitutions are replaced with the STDOUT of the commands inside
- `cpuid` command is put inside process substitution, the STDOUT will be returned as a file descriptor, `grep` will do the necessary matching on it, we have used `grep` with PCRE (`-P`) to get only (`-o`) the desired portion, and `-m1` will stop after first match to avoid repetition
- `printf` is used to get the output in desired format

**Example:**

```
$ printf '%s%s\n' "$(grep -Pom1 'extended model.*\(\K\d+' <(cpuid))" "$(grep -Pom1 'extended family.*\(\K\d+' <(cpuid))"
30
```

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid the intermediate file by using a *pipe*, and you can avoid using both `sed` and `awk` by doing your matching and substitution in `awk` e.g.

```
/usr/bin/cpuid | 
  awk '/extended model/ {mod = substr($4,3)} /extended family/ {fam = substr($4,3)} 
  END {printf "%d%d\n", mod, fam}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without making assumptions and changing the nature of the sample, here is a drop in replacement that stores the output in a variable as requested:

```
CPUID=$(/usr/bin/cpuid)
a=$(echo "$CPUID" | grep 'extended model' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } ')
a+=$(echo "$CPUID" | grep 'extended family' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } ')
```

First line sets the variable `CPUID` to the output of `/usr/bin/cpuid`
I then set the variable `a` to be the output (`echo`) of the `CPUID` variable set in the line above (this is then piped to your provided commands).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This one is the closest to my level of understanding. Unfortunately, I am not expert to sed, awk and perl, but some initial understanding I do have. :-)

Comment: The `cat` in the first line shouldn't be there. It causes CPUID to be assigned the contents of the binary executable rather than its output.

Answer (score 0):

**sed**

```
cpuid | tac | sed '/^CPU/{s/.*//;x;s/\n//g;p;d};/extended \(model\|family\)/!d;s/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/;H;d'
```

as I have 8 cores, my pc emits:

```
50  
50  
50  
50  
50  
50  
50  
50
```

tac reverses the order of lines from cpuid so that I can use ^CPU as a terminator of a CPU record, an also extended model and extended family then occur in the right order

Answer (score 0):

So far, I am reading all the comments, and I will try to use them all. As I wrote to NGRhodes: "unfortunately, I am not expert to sed, awk and perl, but some initial understanding I do have.

Many thanks to all who did/presented these excellent examples. I sincerely hope lot more people will read these lines and deepen their scripting skills!

Actually, I did some cocktail of what you all suggested to me:

```
/usr/bin/cpuid > id.txt  ***[CPUID=$(cat /usr/bin/cpuid) does not work for me]***  
CPUID=id.txt  
a=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'extended model' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } '`)  
a+=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'extended family' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } '`)  
a+=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'AMD' | sed 's/(//' | sed 's/)//' | awk ' { print $13 } '`)  
a+=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'model' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $3 } '`)  
a+=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'stepping id' | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 } '`)  
a+=' '  
a+=$(echo `cat $CPUID | grep -m1 'processor serial number:' | awk ' { print $4 } '`)  
echo $a
```

Result is: **40651 0004-0651-0000-0000-0000-0000** which is what I expect! :-)

Comment: If you're going to do all that and use awk anyway, it would be cleaner to rewrite the whole thing as a small awk program. Also, see my comment to @NGRhodes answer as to why that first line doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't optimize your initial commands, but the semi-colon allows you to put 2 commands together to avoid the concatenation operation entirely:

```
foo="$(firstcommand; secondcommand)"
```

Or, specific to your situation:

```
a=$(grep "extended model" $CPUID | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 };
grep "extended family" $CPUID | sed 's/0x//' | awk ' { print $4 };)
```

If you care about the newlines you will want to put double-quotes before the initial `$(` and after the closing `)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in `awk` (the whole output as done by the code in your answer).

When you end up reprocessing the same input over and over, it usually indicates that another approach might be better.

`awk` is perfect for processing text input like this. `awk` programs are a lot longer than things done with `sed`, but they are much easier to read and you can add print statements to them to make debugging *much* easier.

I left my debugging statements in (commented out). You can uncomment them to watch how the script works.

You have to put the `awk` program somewhere and the easiest place in a single use case like this is to put the whole thing in a single quoted string on the `awk` command line.

This way you don't have to store it in a separate file or in a temporary file, so there's no file management involved and the script will stand on its own.

This program looks long, but it's almost all comments, debugging statements, and white space.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Whole awk program is one single quoted string
## on the awk command line
## so we don't need to put it in a separate file 
## and so bash doesn't expand any of it
## Debugging statements were left in, but commented out

/usr/bin/cpuid | awk '
BEGIN {  ## initialize variables - probably unnecessary
  em = ""
  ef = ""
  fa = ""
  mo = ""
  si = ""
  ps = ""
}

## get each value only once

## extended model is in field 4 starting at the third character
## of a line which contains "extended model"
/extended model/ && em == "" {
  em = substr($4, 3)
  ##print "EM " em
}

## extended family is in field 4 starting at the third character
## of a line which contains "extended family"
/extended family/ && ef == "" {
  ef = substr($4, 3)
  ##print "EF " ef
}

## family is in the last field, starting at the second character
## and is two characters shorter than the field "()"
## of a line which starts with "family"
## (so it does not match "extended family")
$1 == "family" && fa == "" {
  ##print NF " [" $NF "]"
  ##print "[" substr($NF, 2) "]"
  l = length($NF) - 2
  fa = substr($NF, 2, l)
  ##print "FA " fa
}

## model is in the third field, starting at the third character
## of a line which starts with "model"
## (so it does not match "extended model")
$1 == "model" && mo == "" {
  mo = substr($3, 3)
  ##print "MO " mo
}


## stepping id is in field 4 starting at the third character
## of a line which contains "stepping id"
/stepping id/ && si == "" {
  si = substr($4, 3)
  ##print "SI " si
}

## processor serial number is in field 4 starting at the third character
## of a line which contains "processor serial number:"
/processor serial number:/ && ps == "" {
  ps = $4
  ##print "PS " ps
}

## Quit when we have all the values we need
em != "" && ef != "" && fa != "" && mo != "" && si != "" && ps != "" {
  exit
}

END {
  print em ef fa mo si " " ps
}
'
```